# MySQL SHA1 hash does not match

Tags: mysql, passwords, sha

I have a weird problem with a MySQL users table. I have quickly created a simplified version as a testcase.

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `credential` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `credentialSalt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=ucs2 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `identity`, `credential`, `credentialSalt`) VALUES
(1, 'test', '7288edd0fc3ffcbe93a0cf06e3568e28521687bc', '123');
```

And I run the following query

```
SELECT id,
       IF (credential = SHA1(CONCAT('test', credentialSalt)), 1, 0) AS dynamicSaltMatches,
       credentialSalt AS dynamicSalt,
       SHA1(CONCAT('test', credentialSalt)) AS dynamicSaltHash,
       IF (credential = SHA1(CONCAT('test', 123)), 1, 0) AS staticSaltMatches,
       123 AS staticSalt,
       SHA1(CONCAT('test', 123)) AS staticSaltHash
FROM   users
WHERE  identity = 'test'
```

Which gives me the following result

[image]

The dynamic salt does *NOT* match while the static salt *DOES* match.

This is blowing my mind. Can someone help me point out the cause of this?

My MySQL version is **5.5.29**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the default character set of your table. You appear to be running this on a UTF8 database and something in `SHA1()` is having problems with the differing character sets.

If you change your table declaration to the following it will match again:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `credential` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `credentialSalt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/032056/1)

As [robertklep commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001994/mysql-sha1-hash-does-not-match/20002184?noredirect=1#comment29781378_20002184) explicitly casting your string to a character will also work, basically ensure you're using the same characterset when doing comparisons using `SHA1()`

As [the encryption functions documentation says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html):

> Many encryption and compression functions return strings for which the result might contain arbitrary byte values. If you want to store these results, use a column with a VARBINARY or BLOB binary string data type. This will avoid potential problems with trailing space removal or character set conversion that would change data values, such as may occur if you use a nonbinary string data type (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT).

This was [changed in version 5.5.3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1):

> As of MySQL 5.5.3, the return value is a nonbinary string in the connection character set. Before 5.5.3, the return value is a binary string; see the notes at the beginning of this section about using the value as a nonbinary string.

Comment: An explicit cast also seems to fix the problem: `SHA1(CONCAT('test', CAST(credentialSalt AS CHAR)))`

Comment: Yup, thanks @robertklep; I've semi-stolen your comment if you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and helpful answer. In the testcase this fixes the problem! (I accidentally used the wrong charset as u pointed out) However, the original table is UTF8, the column is UTF8, the connection is UTF8 and the problem still persists. The `CAST(... AS CHAR)` *does* also fix the issue on the original table. Do u have any idea what else might be the cause of it?

Comment: What does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';` show you @Maurice?

Comment: it shows me the following: [http://imgur.com/ycKUg5R](http://imgur.com/ycKUg5R) I'm guessing that's not what it should show xD

Comment: The only difference between that and the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/032056/1) is that your database character set is different @Maurice. According to the docs it's determined by `character_set_connection`, which means it should work. Are you sure your table is in `utf8`?

Comment: After doing a `ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` it works as expected! Somehow a wrong charset creeped in there :| Thank you so much for your help! Mind=unblown again